# If $f$ is continuous on a bounded closed interval, then the supremum of $|f|$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

> If $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $\sup_{x ∈ [a,b]}\left | f(x)\right |$ is finite.

Attempt: Suppose $f\colon [a,b]  \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then by the Extreme value theorem, since $[a,b]$ is closed, and $f\colon [a,b]  \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. Then $M =\sup_{x \in [a,b]} \left|f(x)\right|$ is finite.

I don't know if this is fine. Can anyone please help me? Any feedback/hint can help.

Comment: Correct, the boundedness of $|f|$ follows since $f([a,b])$ is bounded (from both above and below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that
$$\sup_{x \in [a, b]} |f(x)| = \max\left(\sup_{x \in [a, b]} f(x), - \inf_{x \in [a, b]} f(x)\right)$$
So knowing that $f$ is bounded -- i.e., that that $\sup f$ and $\inf f$ are finite -- bounds $\sup |f(x)|$ as well.

Comment: why is the infimum negative? In addition M refers to the max of the supremum and the infimum right? Thanks

Comment: Well, if the max of $f$ on the interval is 3 and the min is -5, then the max of $|f|$ on the interval is 5.